# Where would you choose an interface over an abstract base class, when defining a hierarchy?

Tags: java

We have numerous threads talking about the usage of `interface` vis-a-vis `abstract class`

Taking reference of an answer, given by [Prasun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo/7256729#7256729) looks complete answer to me.

Do you think this is complete answer?
Please confirm, if my interpretation of this answer looks correct, considering below example.

The `toEncode()` being part of below abstract class `Critter`, looks wrong to me, because `toEncode()` is not the core behaviour of `Critter`, Consequently sub classes `Shark` `Fish` are implemented as shown below, which looks like a wrong design:

**Critter**

```
/* Critter.java */

package Project1;
    abstract class Critter  {


    Point location;


    public Critter(int x, int y){
        location = new Point(x,y);
    }

    public Point getLocation(){
        return location;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    public abstract String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount);


    public abstract Critter update(Ocean currentTimeStepSea);


}
```

**Shark**

```
/* Shark.java */

package Project1;


class Shark extends Critter{


    public String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount){
        String str = "S";
        str.concat(String.valueOf(this.hungerLevel));
        str.concat(",");
        if(sameNeighborCount > 1)
            str.concat(String.valueOf(sameNeighborCount));
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Fish**

```
/* Fish.java */

package Project1;

class Fish extends Critter{


    public String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount){
        String str = "F";
        if(sameNeighborCount > 1)
            str.concat(String.valueOf(sameNeighborCount));
        return str;
    }
}
```

**RunLengthEncoding**

```
/* RunLengthEncoding.java */

package Project1;
class RunLengthEncoding {

  public RunLengthEncoding(Ocean sea) {
                       .....
              runLengthEncodeObject = sea.cellContents((indexOf2DOcean/sea.getWidth()), Utility.mod(indexOf2DOcean, sea.getWidth())).toRunLengthEncodeSegment(sameNeighborCount);
                        .....
  }
}
```

This above design has issues, because `String toEncode(int)` is currently converting an `int` to  string like ".4" or "S2,3" or "F2", which is specific to `Critter` world, but not core behaviour of `Critter`.

There would be some other new subclass(not part of `Critter` world) in future that can implement such peripheral behaviour `String Encode(int)`. So, `interface` has to capture such behaviours instead of `abstract class`. After placing `interface` in right package(for usage), below example considers this change:

**Critter**

```
/* Critter.java */

package Project1;

abstract class Critter  {


    public abstract IPeripheralBehaviour getBehaviour();
}
```

**IPeripheralBehaviour**

```
/* behaviour.java  */

package Project1;

interface IPeripheralBehaviour{
    public String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount);
}
```

**Shark**

```
/* Shark.java */

package Project1;


class Shark extends Critter implements IPeripheralBehaviour{


    public String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount){
        String str = "S";
        str.concat(String.valueOf(this.hungerLevel));
        str.concat(",");
        if(sameNeighborCount > 1)
            str.concat(String.valueOf(sameNeighborCount));
        return str;
    }


    public IPeripheralBehaviour getBehaviour(){
        return (Shark)this;
    }
}
```

**Fish**

```
/* Fish.java */

package Project1;

class Fish extends Critter implements IPeripheralBehaviour{


    public String toEncode(int sameNeighborCount){
        String str = "F";
        if(sameNeighborCount > 1)
            str.concat(String.valueOf(sameNeighborCount));
        return str;
    }


    public IPeripheralBehaviour getBehaviour(){
        return (Fish)this;
    }
}
```

**RunLengthEncoding**

```
/* RunLengthEncoding.java */

package Project1;

class RunLengthEncoding {

public RunLengthEncoding(Ocean sea) {
                      ....
              behaviour = sea.cellContents((indexOf2DOcean/sea.getWidth()), Utility.mod(indexOf2DOcean, sea.getWidth())).getBehaviour();
              behaviour.toEncode(sameNeighborCount);
                      ....
  }
}
```

This above change does not impact polymorphic behaviour.

Complete code is available [here](https://github.com/shamhub/CS61B_Fall2006/tree/master/JavaCode/src/Project1).

1. Please provide the feedback/comments on my interpretation on usage of `interface`.
2. Word `contract` is used with the concept of `interface`. What exactly is `contract` in this context?

Answer (score 3):

## Elaborating On Prasun's Answer

[Prasun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo/7256729#7256729) is good. However, "core" and "peripheral" are just words without a
precise technical definition. How do you decide what's core and what's peripheral?
So I will elaborate briefly.

**Interface methods allow objects to be handled a certain way**. For example, implementing
an interface might make `Critter`s *comparable*. So that
client code can, in a standard way, sort `Critter`s. This is
why it makes sense to implement multiple interfaces. An object can be comparable and also
serializable at the same time. However, just because an object
is comparable and/or serializable doesn't make it a `Critter`. **Interfaces just guarantee a certain means of interaction**.

On the other hand, extending the abstract class `Critter` definitely makes a class a `Critter`.
An **abstract class** defines what something is in an abstract way; it is **essentially a category**.
An abstract class defines what it is to *be* a critter. As a class, it can also
provide reusable internal components to subclasses.

## 1. Correct Usage of Interface

So you have put `toEncode` in an interface. What is the point of `toEncode`? Does `toEncode`
allow client code to do something with a `Critter` that it might also do with
other objects? If so, it makes sense as an interface method.

## 2. Contract

Implementing an interface is analogous to entering a contract. It sets the rules
of engagement for client code. Interfaces are **enforced** by the compiler. So they are more **like contracts** than guidelines for example.

## General Code Review

### `equals` in `Critter`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Above, all objects of the same class are equal. This will always need to be overridden, so why provide this implementation? If you are sure the subclasses will not introduce
new state variables, then it [might make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200941/does-it-make-sense-to-implement-clone-equals-or-hashcode-for-an-abstract) to implement `equals` **[and `hashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/2537690)** in `Critter`.

### Interface Naming

`IPeripheralBehaviour` is **not** a good name. What behaviour is that exactly? 
See this [discussion about interface naming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901868/2537690).

### Returning the Interface

```
class Shark extends Critter implements IPeripheralBehaviour{

    ...

    public IPeripheralBehaviour getBehaviour(){
        return (Shark)this;
    }
}
```

Do you mean to cast `this` to `IPeripheralBehaviour`? `this` is already a `Shark`.
You could also use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145210/2537690) to
detect whether or not an object implements an interface. I am not sure what this
method is for.

## Comments

In general, I didn't find the comments helpful. This just takes up space:

```
/**
 * The Fish class defines the behavior of a Fish in an Ocean
 * @author
 *
 */

class Fish ...
```

The comment below did not help me understand the method. Could you provide a use case?

```
/**
 * This method call gives reference to access peripheral methods that
 * are part of IPeripheralBehaviour interface which are implemented by
 * Critter object
 * @return Critter object
 */
public abstract IPeripheralBehaviour getBehaviour();
```

## Some Feedback On This Submission

I found this code and your question very difficult to review. It was not
necessary to include the `RunLengthEncoding` class. Including the first design
you didn't like really bulked this question up. The comments were again more bulk. I gave up on this one several times.

Concise, direct questions get more attention. In fact, you will learn quite a
lot just by thoroughly thinking your questions through. The better your questions, the more you will learn. Ask a shorter, easier-to-digest question next time and I guarantee you will get a better response.

I hope this review was of value to you.

Comment: Just removed comments, question looks more precise to me. what i want to know, Is prasun's answer complete(but not good or bad)

Comment: If `interface` can have peripheral behaviour, then why `public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {}` has core behaviours of `list`? here `Collection<E>` is also an interface.

Comment: another point is, yes i donot require casting `return (Shark)this;` but this is not the actual question.

Comment: If by complete you mean exhaustive and comprehensive, no Prasun's answer is not complete. It's just a few sentences.
Complete isn't necessarily useful either. Documentation is often "complete", yet StackOverflow thrives. 
    
*"but this is not the actual question"* But it's part of a **code review**. 

Does the `List` interface "contain core behaviour"? Try and invoke that behaviour with `List<String> P = new List<String>(); P.add("Hello");`
OTOH, `List<E> P = new LinkedList<String>(); P.add("Hello")` works because `LinkedList` is a class that actually implements the `List` interface methods.